# App force closes when using IR sensor of phone

Tags: android, kotlin, infrared, android-app-bundle

I am trying to make an IR emitter app for android, just for fun. I am new to android programming with Kotlin. Whenever I run this app on my phone the app force closes.

```
    val mCIR = getSystemService(Context.CONSUMER_IR_SERVICE) as ConsumerIrManager

    val freq : Int = 38000
    val signal : IntArray = intArrayOf(339,158,19,60,19,20,19,20,19,20,19,60,19,20,19,20,19,20,19,
                                    60,19,60,19,20,19,20,19,20,19,20,19,20,19,20,19,20,19,20,19,20,19,
                                20,19,20,19,60,19,20,19,60,19,20,19,20,19,20,19,60,19,3768)


    pow1.setOnClickListener{
         mCIR.transmit(freq, signal)

    }


}
```

This is the link to the logcat from my device

https://send.firefox.com/download/7ed978957bc24c30/#GFKDhp22ap3qV-6TjTurGg

Comment: Just use `val value : ConsumerIrManager?=null`

Comment: I have tried that, then everything turns to null. I can't use value.transmit(freq, signal).

Comment: No, it is inbuilt class to control IR sensor of the mobile phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can initialize it like this

```
  val value = getSystemService(Context.CONSUMER_IR_SERVICE) as ConsumerIrManager
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it solved my problem. However, now when I use value.transmit(freq, signal), the app force closes.

Comment: Edit your post by adding relevant code and stacktrace.

Comment: you forgot to post your stacktrace.

Comment: I have added the logcat file. Please check it.

Comment: I resolved it. Actually I needed the permission to use IR sensor. Which I had not included in Menifest file. Thank you so much for sticking with me. I really appreciate your help.